# How can I make PROC GMAP (SAS) run is less time?

Tags: shapefile, sql, performance, sas

I am trying to create a map of Australia, by Local Government Area (LGA), with shaded regions displaying the population for each LGA. The shape file can be downloaded from the Australian Bureau of Statistics (ABS) Website. However, the program will not run in a reasonable time period. If I use a subset of the map (say, 100 observations), the code does run, although I get something that is obviously incomplete. If I run the the code with all observations for the map, SAS crashes. There are around 3 million observations in the map, which is too much for SAS to handle.

How can I make Proc GMAP run is less time?

Here is my code:

```
proc mapimport datafile="[insert path]\LGA11aAust.shp" out=mymap;
run;

proc sql;  
create table population_by_lga as
    select distinct lga_code_2011, sum(total) as total
    from caseload2
    group by lga_code_2011
    order by lga_code_2011;
quit;

proc sql;
create table mymap as 
    select *, lga_code11 as lga_code_2011 
    from mymap
    order by lga_code_2011;
quit;

proc gmap data = population_by_lga map = mymap;
  id lga_code_2011;
  choro total;
run;
quit;
```

Comment: It seems like you are exceeding either a hardware or software limitation because you say the same code works on a smaller dataset.  Consequently, I think this is one for the vendor of your software.